# Jquery selector not identifying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

code:

```
<script src="../jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello()
{
    $('#hello'+1).hide();
}
</script>
<?php
$d=1;
$str="<input onclick='hello()' type='text' id='hello".$d."' />";
echo $str;
?>
```

In the above code the textbox should dissapear, but it is not , why?
Is my id selector wrong?
Console says :-  $ not defined so i tried the google cdn for jquery and it worked , thnx a lot to all of you.

Comment: You never call your hello() function ...

Comment: @Idipaolo It's in the `onclick` of the `input`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Remove the onclick handler and the script too, use `$(document).on('click', '#hello1', function(e) {$(this).hide();});`

Comment: Working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/3qkc4/ check your console once.

Comment: @LightStyle i can do in this style doesn't matter, but i want to achieve the id to be in `'#hello'+1` fashion as i can change the variable

Comment: @unknown how come same code not working in mine, should i have to convert the $d to string before appending it to "id"

Comment: @bhawin no, it's not necessary, JS's compiler will do it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said your id can change in any `"hello" + N` I'd recommend using the *startsWith* CSS selector in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[id^="hello"]', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: starts with will hide all the items with id hello, i don't want that

Comment: It will act only on the one clicked. The selector is for the `.on('click', ...)`, it will bind that handler(which will hide the clicked input) to all elements whose id starts with *hello*. It is not going to hide all the elements whose id starts with hello.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the problem is that your `jQuery` is not loaded, because it works fine,change jquery path to this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### DEMO [HERE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9Di66T)

Comment: do browser matters with that as i am using firefox 12

Comment: Man your code is working , juste change path of jquery and test it , it works also in firefox